# In javascript why this reduce method of an array gives this output in below code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, callback, reduce

```js
var check = [1,2,3,4,5];

var check1 = check.reduce((accumulator,element,index,array) => element )

console.log(check1);
//output :5. Why?
```

Comment: it reduces the final result (accumulator) to the what is returned. Since you are not adding (concatenating) the `element` to the accumulator, the only result that is left at the end is the last element in the array - 5.

Comment: Because your always returning the element instead of the accumulator.  Maybe a good idea to read up on reduce -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: To turn the question around, why do you think it _shouldn't_ return `5`?

Comment: Why does it give the output? Because that is how reduce works. Review the documentation to understand what reduce does. You may need to review what a fat arrow does too.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended! It's because your reducer here is returning every item (your `element` parameter) in the array and once we reach the end, we are returning the last item (which happens to be 5).